# Formula evaluation performance in Apache POI

Tags: java, performance, apache-poi

We have a web page where the user can enter any number of excel formula. At the server end, we write all this formula in XSSFWorkbook. These formulas can be dependent to each other so the formula no 100 can refer to the formula 1's value. We execute this formula in sequential order. Our problem is when the number of the formula increases, then it takes more time to execute. Time increases in an exponential manner. It takes more than 30 minutes to evaluate 30k equations and Server usage goes to 100% however it comes back to normal after execution. Threading helps a bit but not satisfactory.

What is the best way to deal with formula evaluation when you have thousands to execute in Apache POI.

Comment: Are you already using [`FormulaEvaluator.evaluateAll()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/FormulaEvaluator.html#evaluateAll())?

Comment: Are you re-using the evaluator plus its associated cache? And what version of Apache POI?

Comment: Use a profiler to find out where the time is actually spent as it likely largely depends on the type of formulas and the cells that you are evaluating, then discuss on the POI mailing list to find out if the required time can be improved.